# Handle HTML tags using python

Tags: python, html

in a HTML-file, I've got the following occurrences:

```
<span class="finereader"></span>
```

or

```
<span class="finereader">a</span>
```

I'd like to remove all these tags. The second example shows that it's possible that there is a letter (or number, but only 1) under the tag. The letter shouldn't be removed, only `<span class="finereader">` and the following `</span>`.
Is there any re.sub-expression which can do this?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('htmlfile'))

for elem in soup.find_all('span', class_='finereader'):
    elem.replace_with(elem.string or '') 

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Isn't it possible using strings or lxml? Because I worked with lxml...and if I understood correctly, BS is just an alternative to lxml, isn't it?

Comment: @MarkF6:`BeautifulSoup` can use several parsers, one of them `lxml`. Take a look to http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. But I've got one last problem: The layout which BS produces (with all the shiftings) isn't helpful to me; in fact, I'd like to have no shiftings at all. Is there a possibility to achieve this using BS?

Comment: @MarkF6: Use `print(soup)` instead of `print(soup.prettify())`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead of using regular expressions for this task.

Then you can do something like this: (used a string in this example as a html file)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<span class="dummy">a</span>
<span>b</span>
</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
for span in soup.find_all('span'):
    print(span.string)

# output:
# a
# b
```